# Issue with WebView and Google Maps

Tags: android

In my application on click of a button i am trying to launch the following url using a web view :

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=indiranagar bangalore&daddr=mgroad bangalore
```

My code is as below:

```
WebView webView=new WebView(this);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

webView.loadUrl("https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=indiranagar bangalore&daddr=mgroad bangalore");
```

When the web view appears it first displays the following:

[image: Web View 1]

And immediately displays the following:

[image: Web View 2]

I do not get to see the maps. Am i missing on something in my code. Can someone kindly help me with this please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i test your code and its working fine . It's show loading process then shows directions.

Comment: Are you trying on an emulator or was it on a device? I tried the above on an 2.3 emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in using Google Maps URL into a ColorBox popup.

I found out that you can add `&output=embed` at the end of the URL to make it show in an iframe.

Maybe this solution will help you too.

So try:

`webView.loadUrl("https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=indiranagar bangalore&daddr=mgroad bangalore&output=embed");`

Answer (score 0):

i found that WebView does not support javascript by default, and this will lead google map jump to a URL that contains a params "nojs",

so, just add this line for your webview, problem gone.

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```